# Laravel cut amount from rows before sum

Tags: php, laravel

I have column in my table where it stores prices and I need to sum those prices, **the issue is I need to cut specific amount from each row before sum them**.

**Example**

```
row 1, column transport = 15000
row 2, column transport = 50000
row 3, column transport = 30000
row 4, column transport = 42000

total will be = 137000
```

I don't want to just sum this numbers, what I need is cut `5000` from each row value and then sum the rest.

So my total after cutting that `5000` will be `117000` and that's the price I'm looking for.

**Code**

> This code return `137000`

```
$month = Order::where('user_id', $userId)->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->month)->sum('transport');
```

Comment: deduction of 5000 is fixed or it varies?

Comment: @RajenTrivedi is fixed

Comment: take count of transport columns, multiply with 5000 store in a variable and deduct it from your sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of running 2 queries and then perform calculation you can do it in a single go as

```
$month  =  Order::where('user_id', $userId)
                ->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->month)
                ->sum(\DB::raw('transport - 5000'));
```

Sample [SQL demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edb393/1) just to show you the internal working of aggregate method `sum()`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
  `amount` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `orders` (`amount`)
VALUES (15000),(50000),(30000),(42000);

select sum(amount),
       sum(amount - 5000)
 from orders

| sum(amount) | sum(amount - 5000) |
|-------------|--------------------|
|      137000 |             117000 |
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have to cut `5000` for every row, I'd do something like this.

```
$tempMonth = Order::where('user_id', $userId)->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->month)->sum('transport');
$countData = Order::where('user_id', $userId)->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->month)->count();

$month = $tempMonth - ($countData * 5000);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$month = Order::where('user_id', $userId)->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->month)->sum('transport');
```

please use transport `amount-rs5000`.
use it before `sum('transport')`